# How to preload Prism views at application startup?

Tags: wpf, view, navigation, preload, prism-4

We use *Prism 4 for WPF* as well as the *navigation functionality* which comes with Prism.

When navigating to (loading) certain views in our application we notice a delay - which understandably comes from instantiating the view and its dependencies, this includes loading necessary assemblies from disk.

We would like to preload these views at application startup while showing a splash screen or something similar.

Has anyone done something similar and would like to share their experiences?

Answer (score 1):

We haven't found a "clean" solution to do this yet. But this is how we have solved it.

In the bootstrapper function InitializeShell() we navigate to all views we want to preload. As last we navigate to all the views we want to show in our homescreen.

```
protected override void InitializeShell()
{
    base.InitializeShell();

    Application.Current.MainWindow = (MainShell) Shell;

    // Preload views
    // ---- Load (navigate to) all views here you want to have preloaded

    // Load actual default views
    // ---- Load (navigate to) the actual views for your "homescreen"

    // Finished loading now show the shell
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

It's not an ideal situation and can give lots of maintenance work if you have a lot of views. This does the job for me, but I'm also interested if anyone has a betters solution.

Comment: That is the kind of thing which I had in mind as well. It's rather a short term solution but there's always hope that the Prism team will come up with a solution to the problem in the future.

Comment: It would be great to be able to leave the responsibility of preloading the views to the modules which contain them. Have you tried to load/navigate to your views at an earlier point during initialization or does that give you errors?

Comment: I have tried to "pre-load" the views in an earlier stage of the bootstrap but this resulted in Null Exceptions, because it had not yet loaded some ViewModels.

Comment: @TimoKosig Can you give me an example of Navigate or load a view?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help or not, but i use the following techniques:
1) add a reference off all needed assemblies to my shell 
2) use busy indicator from [WPF toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home)